# How to upload product list in virtuemart?

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

How can I upload a product list in virtuemart? I have tried to use an extension given in virtuemart website, but it is not working.

Comment: Usually extensions provided on the VirtueMart website are fully functional, so if it's not working, you should not change extension but contact support to get help.
That said, CSV Improved is an excellent product to import / export VirtueMart data.

Comment: That extension is not working.. and not getting response from virtuemart support team as well

Comment: Not sure if we're talking about the same extension... I'll provide a full answer for clarity.

Answer (score -1):

I guess that a question seeking suggestion about a specific product is not in the "true" spirit of SO... that said I am using [CSVImproved](http://www.csvimproved.com) on many VirtueMart sites and I am really satisfied with it, so I strongly suggest it.